# comparison if statment should be called twice but it is only called once when comparing an Integer

Tags: java

I have a function that takes a Integer array and a boolean array.  If the value in the Integer array is the highest value and the boolean array is true, the value in the trackerArray is set to true.  This is a simplified version of my code that produces the error...

```
package com.thisis.a.test;

public class ThisIsATest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer[] integerArray = new Integer[]{75,200,75,200,75};
        boolean[] booleanArray = new boolean[]{false,true,false,true,false};
        boolean[] trackerArray   = new boolean[]{false,false,false,false,false};

        Integer iHighestSum = 0;
        for(int c = 0; c < booleanArray.length; c++){
            if(booleanArray[c] == true)
                if(integerArray[c] > iHighestSum)
                    iHighestSum = integerArray[c];
        }

        for(int c = 0; c < booleanArray.length; c++){
            if(booleanArray[c] == true)
                if(integerArray[c] == iHighestSum) 
                    trackerArray[c] = true; // this if statement should be called twice
        }

        // trackerArray should be {false,true,false,true,false} 
        // instead it is {false,true,false,false,false}
    }
}
```

The trackerArray should be {false,true,false,true,false}, instead it is {false,true,false,false,false}.  The if statment should be triggered twice but instead it is only triggered once.  Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Integer.equals()`, which compares values, not `Integer == Integer`, which compares object references. Your current code literally says "is the second instance of 200 *the same instance* as the first instance of 200"

Two options:

1. Change iHighestSum to `int` ie `int iHighestSum = 0;` Java will [auto-unbox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) the Integer to get its int value, then you will be comparing `ints`, so it's valid to use `==`
2. Change your comparison to use `equals()`:  `if(integerArray[c].equals(iHighestSum))`

As an interesting side note, your code would pass if you changed the values `200` to `127` (or less). This is because the JVM keeps fixed, reusable Objects inside the Integer class for all values between -128 and 127 (ie a "byte"), ie `Integer[] integerArray = new Integer[] { 75, 127, 75, 127, 75 };` passes!

So in summary, either of these changes will make your code function correctly:

```
...
int iHighestSum = 0;
...
if(integerArray[c].equals(iHighestSum))
...
```